# How to split element with display: table in two page using DomPDF

Tags: html, css, dompdf

I've created a PDF file using DomPDF with `display: table` but when I tried to render it, the content can't split in two pages so the content always go to the next page.

It looks like this

```
     Text here




----------------------------------------------------------------       
     +-----------------+-----------------------+
     |  No.            | : ................... |
     +-----------------+-----------------------+
     |  Name.          | : ................... |
     +-----------------+-----------------------+
     |  Address.       | : ................... |
     +-----------------+-----------------------+
```

And all I want is like this

```
    Text Here
    +-----------------+-----------------------+
    |  No.            | : ................... |
    +-----------------+-----------------------+
    |  Name.          | : ................... |
    +-----------------+-----------------------+
----------------------------------------------------------------
    +-----------------+-----------------------+
    |  Address.       | : ................... |
    +-----------------+-----------------------+
```

Is there any solution for this?

Comment: Dompdf can split tables across pages, but it can not split a single table row. You may need to re-evaluate your document structure, to that end some sample HTML would help determine why you're getting these results.